# How to override wxProcess::OnTerminate

Tags: events, wxwidgets, overriding

How can i override `wxProcess::OnTerminate` function to receive events about process teminating with wxWidgets?

I tried to create class overriding `wxProcess` and function `OnTerminate`, but there is no events about it.

How can i override it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can either override `OnTerminate()` in your derived class **or** handle `EVT_PROCESS` event. The two are exclusive, i.e. if you override the method you won't get the event. And if you just want to handle the event, there is no need to override anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you give me an example code of handling `EVT_PROCESS`, wxwidgets quides pretty cheap about `wx/process`

Comment: It's handled in the same way as any other event. If you have any specific problems with it, you can always ask.